# Camel - Stop processing a route on exception

Tags: apache-camel, integration, hl7

I have a camel route which processes hl7 messages. After the processing succeeds I would like to pass it to another endpoint b to do further processing.

But if any exception happens in processHL7, I have a catch block which does some processing. I want to stop processing when I go into the doCatch and encounter end, but this is not happening. Whatever happens the flow is going to endpoint b. How do i stop when I go into the doCatch block?

```
from("direct:a") 
    .doTry()
      .to("bean:processHL7?method=process")        
    .doCatch(HL7Exception.class)
      .to("direct:ErrorACK")
      .transform(ack())
    .end()
    .transform(ack())       
    .to("direct:b");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
from("direct:a") 
    .doTry()
      .to("bean:processHL7?method=process")        
    .doCatch(HL7Exception.class)
      .to("direct:ErrorACK")
      .transform(ack())
      .stop()
    .end()
    .transform(ack())       
    .to("direct:b");
```

You can use `stop()` to stop the route from further processing.